# How to aggregate unique (timestamp) values in Elastic index using aggregation transform or rollup job?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm searching for the best way to store aggregated data in a dedicated index. In the best-case scenario, it should include both historical (already indexed) and newly ingested data. I'm aware of aggregation transforms and rollup jobs and have been testing them out.

Is there any way to get a number of unique timestamp values to store them in the aggregated/rollup index? We need it to monitor ingested data consistency. I can easily get this metric's visualization in Kibana for non-aggregated data, but I see no option to get this metric as a part of my aggregated index.
Is there a way to count unique values and percentiles (namely, medians/50-percentiles) in a rollup job at all? A rollup job seems to perform way faster than an aggregation transfom, and would be more efficient if we'd to scale this practice.

Aggregation transform API throws an error at

```
    "aggregations": {
      "timestamp.cardinality": {
        "cardinality": {
          "field": "@timestamp"
        }
```

and UI doesn't offer an option to to this type of agg.
Same happens when I'm configuring a rollup job.

Any thoughts and suggestions are very much appreciated!